adbでアプリを無効、アンインストール出来ない
pm disable-user --user 0 <パッケージ名>

aShellでとあるアプリを無効にしようとすると
Exception occurred while executing 'disable-user':

と、エラーが出てしまいます
これの解決方法はありますか？
Android13です
